# how to check the divergence of 5 numbers in java

Tags: java

I have an array of five `integers` `count[5]` and I want to check if their difference is more than `3`.

A brute force could be to do : `if(count[5]-count[4])>3) ,if(count[5]-count[3]>3)`

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Is the order of the array important? Using a loop to iterate over each element checking the difference between the next element would work. Look at an "enhanced for loop" and use it to iterate over each element, testing for the difference being greater than 3. Depending what you want the output to look like, this would be a usable solution.

Comment: In one iteration you can find the `min` and `max` values and check their diff.

Comment: @OnlySteveH how will a loop that iterates and checks the diff between an element and the next element find the biggest diff assuming it's between no consecutive items ?

Comment: @alfasin I want to check all the differences and see how many of them are more than three.

Comment: In that case I would sort the array and then your job becomes easier because if the items at indexes 1 and 2 have more than 3 difference you'll know that it's also true for indexes: 1,3 and 1,4

Answer (score 0):

Not a very efficient way to do it, but

```
Integer min = Arrays.<Integer>asList(arr).stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
Integer max = Arrays.<Integer>asList(arr).stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
Integer spread = max - min;
```

will do the trick.

If the array is large, you'll want to do a `reduce` with a running tracker for min and max at the same time. Let me know if you really need that.

Answer (score 0):

**Here a Java code implementation:**

```
public static boolean diff(int[] ar) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(ar[i] - ar[j]) > 3) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use for loop in case if the numbers in the array are to increase.

```
int[5] count = {1,2,3,4,5}
for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < count.length; j++){
   if(((count[i] - count[j]) > 3) || ((count[i] - count[j])<-3)){
      //TODO 
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't check this case for example: `count[0]-count[4]`

Comment: Also, what if `count[0]=-10` and `count[1]=-2`? `count[0]-count[1]=-8`